# Arraylists of arraylist as a representation of relationships

Tags: java, arraylist, graph-algorithm

I have several values, like this: (Elements in a row are in relationship.)

```
       Vertex relationships(edges)
    Source vertex   Destination vertex

    x1 26   y1 287   x2 154   y2 303
    x1 22   y1 114   x2 115   y2 185
    x1 26   y1 287   x2 375   y2 338
    x1 26   y1 287   x2 260   y2 393
    x1 115  y1 185   x2 121   y2 7
    x1 200  y1 101   x2 392   y2 238
    x1 99   y1 394   x2 375   y2 338
    x1 99   y1 394   x2 121   y2 7
    x1 274  y1 28    x2 22    y2 114
    x1 296  y1 185   x2 200   y2 101
    x1 115  y1 185   x2 154   y2 303
```

I should find all the values which are in relationship and put them into a list, like this: `[26,287 154,303 375,338 260,393]`
I have tried to use this code:

```
    for (int i=0; i<vertexnum; i++) {
        adjLists.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    for (int j=0; j<vertexnum; j++) {
        for (Point p : nodes) {
            for (Edge e : edges) {
                adjLists.get(j).add(e.p1.x);
                adjLists.get(j).add(e.p1.y);
                adjLists.get(j).add(0);

                adjLists.get(j).add(e.p2.x);
                adjLists.get(j).add(e.p2.y);
                adjLists.get(j).add(0);
                for (Point p1 : nodes) {
                    for (Edge e1 : edges) {
                        if (e1.p1.x == e.p1.x && e1.p1.y == e.p1.y && !adjLists.get(j).contains(e1.p2.x) && !adjLists.get(j).contains(e1.p2.y)) {
                            adjLists.get(j).add(e1.p2.x);
                            adjLists.get(j).add(e1.p2.y);
                            adjLists.get(j).add(0);
                        } else if(e1.p2.x == e.p1.x && e1.p2.y == e.p1.y && !adjLists.contains(e1.p1.x) && !adjLists.contains(e1.p1.y)){
                            adjLists.get(j).add(e1.p1.x);
                            adjLists.get(j).add(e1.p1.y);
                            adjLists.get(j).add(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It creates only one ArrayList, it gives all elements in a row instead of separately. I have tried debugging, but I can not see what causes this.

Example of what I want:
[image]

Comment: can you post the output you're getting and the output you're expecting?

Comment: Expected output is like this for all vertices(x-y coordinates means a vertex):
[26,287 154,303 375,338 260,393]
[22,114 115,185 274,28]

This code provides a list with all the above coordinates. It only "concatenate" them.

Comment: Why do you loop over `Point p : nodes`? I cannot see where you use `p` inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is unnecessary. Sorry!

Comment: @mum007 if that loop is unnecessary, please update the code in your post to not include it. It's hard to understand what's going on otherwise. Also consider adding a `System.out.println` statement to make it clear what data you're looking at, and include the expected result in your question.

Comment: I have included it. All two phase is done. I really(seemly nobody) can intertpret what is going on with this code.

Comment: Actually, we can't understand what you're asking. Please **edit** your question to include enough code that your code contains the part that actually outputs data from the part that you've already posted. AND include (*in the question*) what your code **actually** prints when you run it.

Comment: Yes, this is also my problem, because this is the only code. I have table above with x-y coordinates as input. That is all. I have wrote the code above to generate the output above. [26,287 154,303 375,338 260,393] That is all, so I do not know how to improve my code. It gives only one long arraylist with thousands of elements.

Comment: I have to store Points with the given x-y's in an arraylist or in a map. That is all, that I have and that I know.

Comment: What do you mean saying *which are in relationship* ? What is *relationship*?

Comment: Relationship means adjacency, points in a line are adjacent/neighbours. As I wrote I have to search for the full neighbour list of a point(x-y coordinates).

Comment: For clarity, I'm merging @mum007's addition to the question (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331525/adjacency-list-in-java) into this question via a suggested edit. It should have been edited into this question, not created as a different one.

Comment: @mum007 This is *not* all of your code. I can tell because it has only the body of a method. Your full code contains a class statement (like `public class IAmNotSureWhatIAmDoing {`) and goes to the end of the file. It also contains no output commands, so there is no way for you to have found out what the algorithm outputs. Please *edit* your question (once the clarification edit suggestion has been merged) to *include the entire file*. Do not simply say that you have posted all of your code. **You have not.** Include **the entire file**, or we will be unable to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take this in three steps: define the data structures, define the problem, provide a solution.

### Define the Data Structures

- Vertex: in your example a vertex seems to be a unique pair of integers. [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) should be a pretty good fit
- Relationship: This seems to be an edge defined by two Vertexes. You should write a simple pojo for this, but for the sake of brevity we'll use [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) from apache commons. Lets declare that the Relationships go from right to left. Thus `Pair<Point, Point> relationship = new ImmutablePair<Point, Point>(new Point(26, 287), new Point(154, 303));` is equivalent to the first line in your example data.

### Define the Problem

You want a method that takes in a list of Relationships and spits out a list of lists showing where one can get to from any given Vertex. I'll take it one further and return map with from points as keys and sets of possible to points as values. ie. `Map<Point,Set<Point>>`

### Solution

At this point the background is clearly defined and finding a solution is easy

```
public static Map<Point, Set<Point>> createTraversalMap(List<Pair<Point, Point>> relationshipList) {
    Map<Point, Set<Point>> traversalMap = new HashMap<Point, Set<Point>>();
    for (Pair<Point, Point> relationship : relationshipList) {
        Point fromVertex = relationship.getLeft(), toVertex = relationship.getRight();
        Set<Point> toSet = traversalMap.get(fromVertex);// set of Vertexes we've found so far for the current "from" Vertex
        if (toSet == null) {// bootstrap the set
            toSet = new HashSet<Point>();
            traversalMap.put(fromVertex, toSet);
        }
        toSet.add(toVertex);
        // traversalMap.put(fromVertex, toSet); //not needed, but good to keep in mind
    }
    return traversalMap;
}
```

*Note, I have not tested this in any way*